# Remove padding in outlook web add-in dialog

Tags: javascript, css, outlook-addin, office-js

This is probably impossible due to the nature of how MS has shaped their office / outlook web `add-in` structure: any add-in runs in an Iframe, communicates with the Office JavaScript API and can trigger dialogs that themselves run in **another** Iframe.

I would like to remove the padding in the below screenshot:
[image]

The padding is (probably) coming from MS' [Fabric style library](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/Dialog/Dialog.html).
The problem is that due to the Iframe nature, one does not have access to override those styles. It is, however, very much impeding styling of the dialog to one's design...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael for reaching out. Yeah we include the padding to encourage a similar feel across the dialogs. Yes you're right that this is coming from Fabric control. Why would you want to remove the padding - would you want to take advantage of that space? Is current design not working well for your UI? If that's the case, a screenshot might help illustrate it, if you could share one.

Comment: Yes and yes. It's a small detail but we would like to design the dialog like the rest of the digital products we offer, for which we use a different design style than diverges here and there from Fabric.

For instance, the division between dialog content and dialog actions as shown in the following screenshot. As it is we can not have the grey divider be 'edgeless':

http://imgur.com/a/tTmVB

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, I have the same problem. Because this unfortunate padding, there is a significant difference between dialog in desktop app and browser. Please remove it.